# How to send HTTP POST request with HTTP header for Xamarin PCL to web service?

Tags: rest, xamarin, http-headers

I am using a PCL project.

I need to send a HTTP POST request with some parameters as well as HTTP header to the web service. The web-service will then return json data back to my client.

How should I do that ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

    public interface IJsonHelper
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<OverallOutlet>> GetData();
    }

    public class JsonHelper : IJsonHelper
    {
        string url = "http://someurl.com";

        public async Task<IEnumerable<OverallOutlet>> GetData()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            // How to add http header (for example, Key : token, Value : 123456) ?
            var post_data = new FormUrlEncodedContent( new [] {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", ""),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", "")
                    });

            var result = await client.PostAsync(url, post_data);
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<OverallOutlet>>(result.ToString());

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Key", "value");` in order to set the request header.

EDIT:

Or you create a `HttpRequestMessage` and add the headers. You can send the message via `client.SendAsync`. Look here http://massivescale.com/custom-headers-with-httpclient/